# How to make hovering over active button not use hover effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, hover

I have a navigation bar that has a hover effect for the buttons. Also whenever a page is active that button has a border on the right to show that it's the page that is currently open. Basically what I want is for the active button to not have a hover effect, because the hover effect covers up the border.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");;
});

function homeTransition()
{   
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage');

    if(document.getElementById("aboutContent").className.indexOf("slideInLeft") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("projectsContent").className.indexOf("slideInUp") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("contactContent").className.indexOf("slideInUp") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    }
    document.getElemenatById("al-saba").className = " animated bounceInDown";
}

function aboutTransition()
{   
    document.getElementById("al-saba").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("aboutContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = "activePage animated slideInLeft";

    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

function projectsTransition()
{   
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage');

    document.getElementById("al-saba").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = "activePage animated slideInUp";

    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

function contactTransition()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage');

    document.getElementById("al-saba").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = "activePage animated slideInUp";

    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

//Menu
$(function() {
    function expand() {
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
        $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
    };

    $('.noselect').click(function() {
        $('.noselect').removeClass('activePage');
        $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
    });

    $(".button").on('click', expand);
});
```

```css
body {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
     color: #ccc;
     z-index: -100;
     background-color: black;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
}
 .menu{
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     width: 250px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     transition: all 250ms;
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
     text-align:center;
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
 .active {
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
     -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
     transition: 0.4s;
     color: #e5e5e5;
}
 ul{
     padding:0;
     list-style:none;
     font-size:14px;
}
 li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: "Raleway";
     width: 250px;
     padding: 40px 5px;
     color: #a7a7a7;
     font-size: 1.8em;
     font-weight: 300;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
 li:hover {
     color: white;
     background-color: #38d8b4;
     -o-transition:.6s;
     -ms-transition:.6s;
     -moz-transition:.6s;
     -webkit-transition:.6s;
     transition:.6s;
}
 .liSeperator {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 1px;
     color: (0, 0, 0, .4);
}
 .content {
     position: relative;
     width: 240px;
}
 .button {
     width:22px;
     height:40px;
     margin:80px 97px;
     padding: 10px;
     cursor:pointer;
     transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
 .button:hover{
     transform: scale(1.2);
}
 .line {
     width: 40px;
     height: 2px;
     background-color:#fff;
     transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}
 .line.first{
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}
 .line.second{
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}
 .button.on .line.top{
     width: 40px;
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}
 .button.on .line.bottom{
     width: 40px;
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}
 .activePage li {
     transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
     color: white;
     border-right: 8px solid #38d8a1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
                                    <div class="menu">
                                        <h1 class="noselect">MENU</h1>
                                        <ul>
                                                <li id="home" class="noselect" onclick="homeTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> home
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="about" class="noselect" onclick="aboutTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> about                                        
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="projects" class="noselect" onclick="projectsTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-code"></i> projects
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="contact" class="noselect" onclick="contactTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> contact
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content animated fadeInDown">
                                        <div class="button">
                                            <div class="line first top"></div>
                                            <div class="line second bottom"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: your html is invalid - div and li need to be swapped around - ul can not have div as direct child

Comment: Ok I changed the html

Comment: You have an error in your JavaScript; please fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pete said, your HTML is invalid. But you can exclude the `.activePage` class using `:not()` with your `:hover` selector.

So instead of `li:hover` use `.noselect:not(.activePage) li:hover`

```js
//Menu
$(function() {
    function expand() {
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
        $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
    };

    $('.noselect').click(function() {
        $('.noselect').removeClass('activePage');
        $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
    });

    $(".button").on('click', expand);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}

.active {
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  width: 250px;
  padding: 40px 5px;
  color: #a7a7a7;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.noselect:not(.activePage) li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #38d8b4;
  -o-transition: .6s;
  -ms-transition: .6s;
  -moz-transition: .6s;
  -webkit-transition: .6s;
  transition: .6s;
}

.liSeperator {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px;
  color: (0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
}

.button {
  width: 22px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 80px 97px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.line {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}

.line.first {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.line.second {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}

.button.on .line.top {
  width: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}

.button.on .line.bottom {
  width: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}

.activePage li {
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
  border-right: 8px solid #38d8a1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <h1 class="noselect">MENU</h1>
    <ul>
      <div id="home" class="noselect" onclick="homeTransition()">
        <li>
          <i class="fa fa-home"></i> home
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="liSeperator"></div>
      <div id="about" class="noselect" onclick="aboutTransition()">
        <li>
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> about
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="liSeperator"></div>
      <div id="projects" class="noselect" onclick="projectsTransition()">
        <li>
          <i class="fa fa-code"></i> projects
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="liSeperator"></div>
      <div id="contact" class="noselect" onclick="contactTransition()">
        <li>
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> contact
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content animated fadeInDown">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="line first top"></div>
      <div class="line second bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I actually forgot to include all of the javascript... sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your CSS:

```
 .activePage li:hover {
   border-right: 8px solid #38d8a1;
   background: black;
 }
```

This will keep your `border-right:` and `background` the same and not trigger the hover effect that your other `li` elements receive.

Working Fiddle - https://fiddle.jshell.net/0nw77chv/ (CSS added at the bottom)