# How to make hovering over an active button not use hover effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hover

I have a navigation bar that has a hover effect for the buttons. Also whenever a page is active that button has a border on the right to show that it's the page that is currently open. Basically what I want is for the active button to not have a hover effect, because the hover effect covers up the border.

Don't worry about the errors, I just didn't include the pages that slide onto the page when the buttons are clicked.

```js
function homeTransition()
{   

    if(document.getElementById("aboutContent").className.indexOf("slideInLeft") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("projectsContent").className.indexOf("slideInUp") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("contactContent").className.indexOf("slideInUp") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    }
    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceInDown";
}

function aboutTransition()
{   
    
    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("aboutContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = "activePage animated slideInLeft";

    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

function projectsTransition()
{   

    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = "activePage animated slideInUp";

    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

function contactTransition()
{

    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = "activePage animated slideInUp";

    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

//Menu
$(function() {
    function expand() {
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
        $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
    };

    $('.noselect').click(function() {
        $('.noselect').removeClass('activePage');
        $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
    });

    $(".button").on('click', expand);
});
```

```css
body {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
     color: #ccc;
     z-index: -100;
     background-color: black;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
}
.menu{
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     width: 250px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     transition: all 250ms;
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
     text-align:center;
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
 .active {
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
     -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
     transition: 0.4s;
     color: #e5e5e5;
}
 ul{
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: .875em;
}
 li{
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: "Raleway";
     width: 250px;
     padding: 16% 2%;
     color: #a7a7a7;
     font-size: 1.8em;
     font-weight: 300;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
 li:hover {
     color: white;
     background-color: #38d8b4;
     -o-transition: .6s;
     -ms-transition: .6s;
     -moz-transition: .6s;
     -webkit-transition: .6s;
     transition: .6s;
}
 .activePage li {
   transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
   border-right: 8px solid #38d8a1;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);;
 }
 .liSeperator {
     width: 100%;
     padding: .5%;
     color: (0, 0, 0, .4);
}
 .content {
     position: relative;
     width: 240px;
}
 .button {
     width:22px;
     height:40px;
     margin:80px 97px;
     padding: 10px;
     cursor:pointer;
     transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
 .button:hover{
     transform: scale(1.2);
}
 .line {
     width: 40px;
     height: 2px;
     background-color:#fff;
     transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}
 .line.first{
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}
 .line.second{
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}
 .button.on .line.top{
     width: 40px;
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}
 .button.on .line.bottom{
     width: 40px;
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
                                    <div class="menu">
                                        <h1 class="noselect">MENU</h1>
                                        <ul>
                                                <li id="home" class="noselect" onclick="homeTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> home
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="about" class="noselect" onclick="aboutTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> about
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="projects" class="noselect" onclick="projectsTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-code"></i> projects
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="contact" class="noselect" onclick="contactTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> contact
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content animated fadeInDown">
                                        <div class="button">
                                            <div class="line first top"></div>
                                            <div class="line second bottom"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question 3 hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349258/how-to-make-hovering-over-active-button-not-use-hover-effect

Comment: How is this different than [what you just asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349258/how-to-make-hovering-over-active-button-not-use-hover-effect/43349472#43349472)?

Comment: I thought that the answer that I selected removed the divs around the li's. But it didn't, and I removed them myself and tried to make it work. But I have had no success.

Comment: Please continue with the other question and comment there. Duplicates won't double helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.activePage` selector is wrong. Needs to be `.activePage`, not `.activePage li`.

Then same answer as before - use `:not()` to exclude `.activePage` from your `:hover` selector with `li:not(.activePage):hover`

```js
function homeTransition()
{   

    if(document.getElementById("aboutContent").className.indexOf("slideInLeft") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("projectsContent").className.indexOf("slideInUp") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("contactContent").className.indexOf("slideInUp") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    }
    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceInDown";
}

function aboutTransition()
{   
    
    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("aboutContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = "activePage animated slideInLeft";

    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

function projectsTransition()
{   

    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = "activePage animated slideInUp";

    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

function contactTransition()
{

    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = "activePage animated slideInUp";

    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

//Menu
$(function() {
    function expand() {
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
        $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
    };

    $('.noselect').click(function() {
        $('.noselect').removeClass('activePage');
        $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
    });

    $(".button").on('click', expand);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}

.active {
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: .875em;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  width: 250px;
  padding: 16% 2%;
  color: #a7a7a7;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

li:not(.activePage):hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #38d8b4;
  -o-transition: .6s;
  -ms-transition: .6s;
  -moz-transition: .6s;
  -webkit-transition: .6s;
  transition: .6s;
}

.activePage {
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  border-right: 8px solid #38d8a1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  ;
}

.liSeperator {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5%;
  color: (0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
}

.button {
  width: 22px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 80px 97px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.line {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}

.line.first {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.line.second {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}

.button.on .line.top {
  width: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}

.button.on .line.bottom {
  width: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <h1 class="noselect">MENU</h1>
    <ul>
      <li id="home" class="noselect" onclick="homeTransition()">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> home
      </li>
      <div class="liSeperator"></div>
      <li id="about" class="noselect" onclick="aboutTransition()">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> about
      </li>
      <div class="liSeperator"></div>
      <li id="projects" class="noselect" onclick="projectsTransition()">
        <i class="fa fa-code"></i> projects
      </li>
      <div class="liSeperator"></div>
      <li id="contact" class="noselect" onclick="contactTransition()">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> contact
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content animated fadeInDown">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="line first top"></div>
      <div class="line second bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, the previous answer wasnt working for some reason

Comment: @OpticLukie because you changed the HTML structure.

Comment: @OpticLukie if this answer has helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yeah this is the def the answer.

Comment: @OpticLukie did this resolve the issue? If so you should mark it as the solution so people know.